# Can I make new cryptocurrency on top of ethereum blockchain tech.?

Tags: solidity, web3js, dapps

Can I make new cryptocurrency on top of ethereum blockchain tech.?
How can i make new cryptocurrency on top of ethereum blockchain tech.?
Any api or platform? Process? Answer will be appreciated... 
Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`Can I make new cryptocurrency on top of ethereum blockchain tech.?`

The question is very ambiguous. There are two ways you can build a crypto currency.

1. Create separate blockchain using the same Ethereum tooling
   Ethereum for instance has its old fork being maintained as Ethereum Classic. You can create a new genesis file, and use a different network id to form a new crypto network using Ethereum clients like Geth and Parity. All your nodes will have to use the same genesis file and network id.
2. Create a Token on top of Ethereum public blockchain (homestead)
   ERC20 is a Token Contract specification being widely used. GOLEM, MAK, etc. are examples. You can publish a ERC20 Token contract on Ethereum by adding fixed number of units for circulation.

https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard